# C++ anonymous struct unusual definition

Tags: c, struct, anonymous-struct

Looking at some .h script I saw this:

```
struct
{
  int resource;
} SimulRes[SIMULRES];
```

Where SIMULRES is define above as:

```
#define SIMULRES 50
```

I assume this is an anonymous struct but I am used to seeing it defined inside a named struct instead. How does this behave with different c++ compilers? What does parameter inside square brackets do?
Thanks.

Comment: What's so weird about this? You can simply use it like this: `SimulRes[0].resource = 20;`

Comment: Ok, sorry for that stupid question. The context it was used in was what made it weird for me and failed to share that context here.

Answer (score 3):

This definition creates an array of size `SIMULRES` of an anonymous `struct`.

Because the struct type is anonymous, you can't pass it to a function or create any other instances (or pointers) other that the one that has already been defined.

Answer (score -1):

This is not C++ syntax, but a C syntax.

It merely means defining an array `SimulRes`, of 50 (`SIMULRES`) elements, where type of the elements is a struct having a single item `resource`.